# capybara visit url with reserved character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, uri

I want to visit a url returned from an API. Url looks like this:
`http://domain/#CollectionPlace:{\"id\":\"2101612070000671031\"}`

When I call visit on this Capybara returns `bad URI(is not URI?):(URI::InvalidURIError)` error. I have tried to manually tried `URI.encode(url)` and `URI.encode(UR.parse(url)` but looks like I need to retain the `#` in the url for it to work.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Try `Addressable::URI.heuristic_parse(url).site` That should return what you want.

Comment: Thanks @DMH. Worked like a charm.

Comment: awesome I have add it as a answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Addressable::URI.heuristic_parse(url).site
```

Will give you what you need.